# more than one clickable list in html

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = (event)=>{
      const li = document.createElement('li');
    };

  document.querySelector("#add-message li,#add-message2 li").addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('You have clicked: ',this.textContent);
    });

  li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#message').value;
  document.querySelector('#add-message').append(li);  
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<ul id="add-message">
</ul>

<ul id="add-message2">
  <li>ab</li>
  <li>ss</li>
  <li>sss</li>
</ul>

<ul id="add-message3">
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>ssw</li>
  <li>ssst</li>
</ul>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="message">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

I want make `add-message` and `add-message2` `li` element to be only clickable.
But it give null error.
I try to select element using selector like in CSS, descendant combinator 
but it failed to select `li`

Right now I am selecting `li` from `#add-message` and `#add-message2`

Comment: For your `document.querySelectorAll("li").addEventListener`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method . Also look up how scoping works in JS - your `li` is not in scope when you try to assign to its `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select just one `<li>` item and hope that all of them will follow.

That's the code that works.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = (event) => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#message').value;
        document.querySelector('#add-message').append(li);
        event.preventDefault();
        // note the lines added here ↓↓↓
        li.addEventListener('click', function() {
                console.log('You have clicked', this.textContent);
            });
        // add an item into the second list
        const li2 = document.createElement('li');
        li2.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#message').value;
        document.querySelector('#add-message2').append(li2);
        event.preventDefault();
        li2.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('You have clicked', this.textContent);
        });
    };

    // and don't forget the loop here ↓↓↓
    for (let li of document.querySelectorAll("#add-message li, #add-message2 li")) {
        // here ↓↓↓ you should add event listeners to list items one by one
        li.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('You have clicked', this.textContent);
        });
    }

});
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="message">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<ul id="add-message">
</ul>

<ul id="add-message2">
    <li>ab</li>
    <li>ss</li>
    <li>sss</li>
</ul>

<ul id="add-message3">
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>ssw</li>
    <li>ssst</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: for (let li of document.querySelectorAll("#add-message li, #add-message2 li")) {
 is not working  when list is changed to  for (let li of document.querySelectorAll("#add-message ")  then it is printing all li inside add-message not just clicked one

Comment: @green-seek, done. What browser do you use? The code is working fine for me.

Comment: your code is working, i tried on two input form .but there i used for loop so it didn't work. your code is really easy to understand ,  please add one form to make it clickable.

Comment: I don't get it. What for do you want to be clickable? What do you mean by that? There is only one form, so where is the second one you're talking about?

Comment: i have 2  <input>  in < form >and one <submit> button , i want  value from them in <li > in  two different <ul> for each,   both  of them clickable

Comment: If you want to append the entered text into two lists at a time, I have changed the answer accordingly. All new items are clickable. And you have 2 `input`s, one of which is Submit button, not “and”.

Comment: it is still not working , when used #add-channels it  is collecting all li and with  # add-channel li  it is not working    https://github.com/rupesh2017/local-storage-chat-note-app/blob/master/final(notworking)3/templates/chat.html                             https://github.com/rupesh2017/local-storage-chat-note-app/blob/master/final(notworking)3/static/index.js

Comment: Okay, I'm catching up. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) out, namely the part after “Do not reuse generators” title. **TL;DR** Replace `of` with `in` inside `for(…)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try code below. all levels are clear. pay attention to correct place of `li` var Which leads to the error that you receive it. also look at the second `event listener`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
   document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = (event)=>{
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#message').value;
      document.querySelector('#add-message').append(li);  
      event.preventDefault();
   };

  document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('click', function(ev){
    var tN = ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if(tN!="li") return;
    var ul = ev.target.parentNode,
        uid = ul.id;
    if(uid.indexOf("add-message")!=0) return;
    var li=ev.target;
    console.log('You have clicked: ',li.textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

        <form>
          <input type="text" id="message">
          <input type="submit" id="submit">
        </form>

        <ul id="add-message">

        </ul>

        <ul id="add-message2">
            <li>ab</li>
            <li>ss</li>
            <li>sss</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="add-message3">
          <li>abc</li>
          <li>ssw</li>
          <li>ssst</li>
      </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

---

Another benefit of this method is that if you dynamically create new `ul`s (that their Id starts with `add-message`), this program will still work!